# Ponteiro de ponteiro para alocar um vetor em uma função

Tags: c, array, funções, alocação

Estou com dificuldade para conseguir resolver um problema de uma lista de exercícios. a questão é a seguinte:
Escreva uma função que recebe como parâmetro dois valores inteiros tam e lim, aloca dinamicamente um vetor de
tamanho tam, preenche esse vetor com valores aleatórios de 0 a lim e retorna esse vetor alocado e preenchido.
Protótipo: `int * criaVetor(int tam, int lim);`
Desafio: Modifique a função do item a) para que seja do tipo void. Para isso vc deverá considerar que a função recebe
o endereço de um ponteiro (**) (que estava apontando para lugar desconhecido e que agora deverá apontar para o
bloco alocado). A função deve preencher o vetor com valores aleatórios de -lim a lim.
Protótipo: `void criaVetorPorReferencia(int **v, int tam, int lim);`

O mais perto que consigo de fazer funcionar é implementando esse código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void criaVetorPorReferencia(int **v, int tam, int lim)
{
    int i;
    int lower=lim*-1;
    int upper=lim;
    srand(time(0));

    v=(int*)malloc(tam*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
    {
        v[i]=0;
    }

}
int main()
{
    int *v;
    int tam;
    int lim;
    int i;
    v=&v;

    printf("Insira a quantidade de elementos do vetor e o limite do valor dos elementos \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&tam,&lim);

    criaVetorPorReferencia(v,tam,lim);


    for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }

    free(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Porém, ele plota o vetor com números aletaórios(lixo) ao invés de inserir os valores dentro do vetor. No que eu estou errando ? É um erro de lógica ou de sintaxe ?

Answer (score -1):

> Porém, ele plota o vetor com números aletaórios(lixo) ao invés de inserir os valores dentro do vetor. No que eu estou errando ? É um erro de lógica ou de sintaxe ?

Há erros de lógica e de sintaxe.

Antes de tudo deixou de seguir a especificação do que tem que fazer. Está claro que tem que escrever a função

```
     int * criaVetor(int tam, int lim);
```

e depois modificar tal função para

```
    void criaVetorPorReferencia(int **v, int tam, int lim);
```

> A função deve preencher o vetor com valores aleatórios de -lim a lim

Não escreveu nada disso. Apenas colocou `0` no que seriam os elementos do vetor e isso já faz parte dos erros de sintaxe. O compilador deve ter emitido vários warnings que você igonorou ou omitiu simplesmente.

Essa linha não faz sentido:

```
    v = &v;
```

### Sobre o código postado

#### `srand()`

- Náo precisa incluir `time.h` apenas para chamar com `0` e iniciar o gerador de números aleatórios. Sequer precisa inicializar tal gerador porque seu programa usa uma única série de números uma única vez.
- Iniciar o gerador pode ser útil usando uma constante, porque assim a série se reproduz toda vez que rodar o programa. Isso é mais útil do que usar uma semente aletória para que a série nunca se repita.
- `time(now)` ou `time(0)` se usa por exemplo no caso de jogos, sorteios em que se espera que a série seja sempre diferente. Aqui --- e em todos os programas desse tipo ao menos enquanto estão em teste --- o contrário é mais útil.
- você nunca chamou `rand()` que é a função que te traria os tais números aleatórios

#### `rand()` e números aleatórios em um intervalo conhecido

O modo comum de conseguir esses números é considerar que de `-lim` a `lim` tem `lim + lim + 1` valores e usar o operador módulo `%` para ter os números.
`rand()` retorna um valor inteiro positivo entre `0` e `RAND_MAX` que pode ser `32768` então a conta que se usa é

```
        -lim + rand() % (lim + lim + 1)
```

Quando `rand()` retorna `0` a soma dá `-lim` e o maior valor possível vai ser `lim + lim` e a soma será `lim`, mantendo os valores no intervalo certo.

Essa função mostra na tela `n` valores entre `-lim` e `lim`, 5 por lihha:

```
void t_rand(const int n, const int lim)
{ 
    const int nc = 5; // 5 por linha
    for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < n; i += 1)
    {
        if (++c > nc) c = 1, printf("\n");
        printf("%6d ", -lim + rand() % (lim + lim + 1));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

para

```
    srand(220518);
    t_rand(30, 8);
```

pode mostrar

```
    -7     -4      3     -3     -5
    -4      8     -2      3      6
     7     -3     -1      6     -7
     5      2      8      4      1
     5     -6      3     -1      2
     3     -3     -7      2     -8
```

#### A função `criaVetor(int tam, int lim);`

partindo do exemplo acima a função deve:

- alocar um vetor do tamanho certo
- preencher usando aquela conta
- retornar o endereço

Enão uma possível implementação:

```
int* criaVetor(int tam, int lim)
{
    int* v = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * tam);
    if (v == NULL) return NULL;
    int len = lim + lim + 1;
    for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < tam; i += 1)
        v[i] = -lim + rand() % len;
    return v;
}
```

só copiando da outra função.

É claro que vai precisar de uma função para mostrar os valores gerados então a mesma função de exemplo pode servir para gerar

```
void mostraVetor(const int n, int* v, const char* tit)
{
    const int nc = 5;  // 5 por linha
    if (v == NULL) return;
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < n; i += 1)
    {
        if (++c > nc) c = 1, printf("\n");
        printf("%6d ", v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

O terceiro parâmetro é um título opcional e é muito conveniente. Veja no EXEMPLO ao final

#### A função (b) `criaVetorPorReferencia()`

Claro que a função do item (a) faz a mesma coisa. A mudança está  apenas no retorno e nos argumentos e a nova função deve ser algo como

```
void criaVetorPorReferencia(int** v, int tam, int lim)
{
    int* vetor = criaVetor(tam, lim);
    *v         = vetor;
}
```

Não há razão para duplicar o código a menos que o tempo de chamar a outra função fosse realmente importante.

#### `main()` para testar isso

```
int main(void)
{
    int tam = 30;
    int lim = 8;
    //srand(220518);
    //t_rand(tam, lim);

    srand(220518);
    int* vetor   = criaVetor(tam, lim);
    char msg[80] = {0};
    sprintf(
        msg, "\n(a) Usando criaVetor(%d,%d)\n", tam, lim);
    mostraVetor(tam, vetor, msg);
    free(vetor);  // apaga

    srand(220518);
    int* outro_vetor = NULL;
    criaVetorPorReferencia(&outro_vetor, tam, lim);
    sprintf( msg,"\n(b) Usando "
        "criaVetorPorReferencia(int**,%d,%d)\n",
        tam, lim);
    mostraVetor(tam, outro_vetor, msg);
    free(outro_vetor);
    return 0;
}
```

O mínimo. Note que

- o gerador sendo reiniciado entre a primeira e a segunda função serve como garantia de que a sequência vai ser reproduzida.
- o ponteiro poderia claro ser o mesmo

#### saída do exemplo

```
(a) Usando criaVetor(30,8)

    -7     -4      3     -3     -5
    -4      8     -2      3      6
     7     -3     -1      6     -7
     5      2      8      4      1
     5     -6      3     -1      2
     3     -3     -7      2     -8

(b) Usando criaVetorPorReferencia(int**,30,8)

    -7     -4      3     -3     -5
    -4      8     -2      3      6
     7     -3     -1      6     -7
     5      2      8      4      1
     5     -6      3     -1      2
     3     -3     -7      2     -8
```

Apagando o `srand()` entre as chamadas:

```
(a) Usando criaVetor(30,8)

    -7     -4      3     -3     -5
    -4      8     -2      3      6
     7     -3     -1      6     -7
     5      2      8      4      1
     5     -6      3     -1      2
     3     -3     -7      2     -8

(b) Usando criaVetorPorReferencia(int**,30,8)

    -2      4      6      0      8
     0     -5      6     -3      3
     1     -1     -6      4     -2
    -7      8     -3     -7     -2
     5     -6      0      5      2
    -7      5      5     -8     -5
```

O código completo

```
// https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/553085/
// ponteiro-de-ponteiro-para-alocar-um-vetor-em-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void criaVetorPorReferencia(int** v, int tam, int lim);
int* criaVetor(int tam, int lim);

void t_rand(const int, const int);
int* criaVetor(int, int);
void criaVetorPorReferencia(int**, int, int);
void mostraVetor(int, int*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    int tam = 30;
    int lim = 8;
    //srand(220518);
    //t_rand(tam, lim);

    srand(220518);
    int* vetor   = criaVetor(tam, lim);
    char msg[80] = {0};
    sprintf(
        msg, "\n(a) Usando criaVetor(%d,%d)\n", tam, lim);
    mostraVetor(tam, vetor, msg);
    free(vetor);  // apaga

    //srand(220518);
    int* outro_vetor = NULL;
    criaVetorPorReferencia(&outro_vetor, tam, lim);
    sprintf( msg,"\n(b) Usando "
        "criaVetorPorReferencia(int**,%d,%d)\n",
        tam, lim);
    mostraVetor(tam, outro_vetor, msg);
    free(outro_vetor);
    return 0;
}

void t_rand(const int n, const int lim)
{
    const int nc = 5;  // 5 por linha
    for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < n; i += 1)
    {
        if (++c > nc) c = 1, printf("\n");
        printf("%6d ", -lim + rand() % (lim + lim + 1));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void mostraVetor(const int n, int* v, const char* tit)
{
    const int nc = 5;  // 5 por linha
    if (v == NULL) return;
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < n; i += 1)
    {
        if (++c > nc) c = 1, printf("\n");
        printf("%6d ", v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int* criaVetor(int tam, int lim)
{
    int* v = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * tam);
    if (v == NULL) return NULL;
    int len = lim + lim + 1;
    for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < tam; i += 1)
        v[i] = -lim + rand() % len;
    return v;
}

void criaVetorPorReferencia(int** v, int tam, int lim)
{
    int* vetor = criaVetor(tam, lim);
    *v         = vetor;
}
```

Comment: Então a resposta é inútil? E porque seria? Ah o stack overflow e o anonimato. A resposta disse o que está errado, discuti uo problema, tem um exemplo completo com a saída. Mas é inútil. É preciso mais esforço!